# Sort collections page by Product SKU?

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to sort the Collections pages by product SKU (instead of product name, featured, etc)?I have checked the theme's collection-sorting.liquid file, but it doesn't show SKU sorting as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually sort by SKU (use your mouse and drag'n'drop) or if you don't want to manually sort, you can use a script to sort a collection by SKU. It is likely not built-in by Shopify as it is not really something most people would want to do.